# Subscribe user with pushPad Express to a custom Tag

Tags: notifications, web-push, push-api, pushpad

I'm ussing pushpad Express to create a custom notification centre for a webapp, Subscribe is working fine with Uids, but I can't make it work with tags filtering. I check the documentation but I can't find the correct parameter name for this.
I tried "tags[]=demo", tags=["demo"],tags=demo, a lot of things, But it doesn't work.

```
MyApp.pathFor = function (uid) {
      return encodeURI(this.path() + '?ui=false&suggest_tags=demo2&uid=' + uid + '&uid_signature=' + this.GenerateUserAuthKey(uid));
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushpad Express has only partial support for tags (you can only add them with the REST API, by updating an existing subscription).

If you need tags, I strongly recommend that you **use Pushpad Pro**.

Otherwise, if you want to use Express and you have a small number of topics (tags), you can **create a project for each topic** (the sender can be the same).

**Note**: we don't support tags for Express because they would be difficult to change; it's much easier to update tags with the Javascript SDK (Pushpad Pro)